# asp.net scrollbars on empty textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, scrollbar

I have a textbox as follows:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="100px" Rows="3" ReadOnly="true"
 BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("Notes") %>'
 BackColor="#222222" ForeColor="White"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I make it so that the vertical scrollbar is not displayed when the textbox is either empty or it doesn't need to scroll because the text fits in the 3 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with CSS by specifying `overflow:auto;`.  You can manually add this attribute to the `CssStyleCollection` at `TextBox1.Style` in your page's code-behind, or you can apply a `CssClass` value declaratively and define the css class in an external stylesheet.

Here is some documentation on CSS `overflow` : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html

Here is some documentation on the `TextBox.Style` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.style

Comment: Thanks. I've added it to the CSS since I will be using it a lot.